# Reading and inserting data into a different server

Tags: sql, sql-insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to insert data into a different server

```
INSERT INTO   "Database2"."Schema2"."Table2"
(SELECT * FROM "Database1"."Schema1"."Table1")
```

If Database1 is coming from SERVER A and Database2 is SERVER B?

Comment: Hi Steve, can you elaborate if you are trying inside Snowflake UI or what is your platform that you are trying on? if you are getting error what is the details, please?

Comment: same snowflake but 2 different servers, trying to insert with SQL but not sure the syntax

Comment: I think you mean two accounts, then. As there is no server concept in Snowflake cloud. Assuming so, then either one of the accounts must have access to the other account's database  by secure sharing https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html as a simple way or data exchange/replication if this need comprehensive solution in two ways direction. 

Correct me if I'm wrong are you able to see the other database in your left pane (object explorer) in your current account? it must be there first in order to select data from it.